# How can I set a default php.ini path for PHP CLI on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, configuration, command-line-interface

**Brief introduction to the problem:**

I need to load *pdo_mysql* to run command `php app/console doctrine:database:create` and other commands for [Symfony 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony).

I found a way to do this by running `php -c "path/to/my/php.ini" app/console doctrine:database:create`

**Problem:**

Since I don't want to add the path to my php.ini every time I run commands in PHP CLI, **where/how can I set up Windows, so that every time I type** `php somecommand` **in console it will load my desired php.ini file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add `path/to/your/php.ini` to the path environment variable and then just run `php -c "php.ini" app/console doctrine:database:create`

Could you try that?

Comment: That works, thanks! That's definately shorter/quicker than writing the whole path.

Comment: Probably, `php app/console doctrine:database:create` will also work, since the `php.ini` is already in the path.

Answer (score 3):

Create a .CMD file which automatically runs PHP with the required options:

```
path/to/php.exe -c "path/to/php.ini" %1 %2 %3 % %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

and call it something like `phpcli.cmd`. Make sure it's on your search path and off you go. The only change you need to make is to run phpcli rather than php.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do it, but if you don't want to mess with an alias or making multiple copies of file *php.ini*, you can also set the PHPRC environment variable.  I would think this is the recommended method to set it more "permanently".

More information in the PHP documentation:
*[The configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)*

In Windows, an easy way to do this is to go to the "System Properties" dialog; either right-click on "My Computer" and click "Properties", or use the "System" item in Control Panel, then go to "Advanced" settings, click "Environment Variables", and click "Add" for either the system or your user, call it "PHPRC" and copy the path to your *.ini* file in there ... for example, mine was in `C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.28`.

(This was on Windows 7, and they changed some of the UI in different versions, but it's basically the same.)

You can verify it's working by doing `php --ini` from the command line. The output should be something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\MAMP\conf\php5.6.28\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

You can also do `echo %PHPRC%` from the Windows command prompt, or `echo $PHPRC` from [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)/Bash/[MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW), etc.  You will have to restart any existing terminal sessions for this to take effect, but in my experience it works for all three, since the bash environments also inherit the Windows environment variables.