# MySQLi not found error

Tags: php, mysqli, iis-5

I just deployed my website to a staging environment and am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in D:\ClientSites\baileyboiler.com\www\new\php\db.php on line 11
```

At first I assumed that MySQLI was simply not installed, but running a `phpinfo()` reveals the following:

[image]

To me it looks like MySQLI is installed (though I could be reading this wrong). What should I do?

**Code**

```
class DB
{
    public static function GetConnection()
    {
        return new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DEFAULTDATABASE);
    }
}
```

(line 11 is the `return new mysql(...);`)

**Update**

I added `extension=php_mysqli.dll` to my php.ini located at `/Windows/php.ini` (according to `phpinfo()`, this is the one being loaded):

```
Loaded Configuration File   C:\WINDOWS\php.ini
```

But the error persists. I know that mysqli.dll exists at `C:\php\ext` - because I can see the file. What now?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Try finding `extension=php_mysqli.so` in your `php.ini` (if on a Linux server) `php_mysqli.dll` <=(on a Windows server) and remove comment in front of it. Then restart your webserver after making changes in php.ini - Or you may need to install MySQLi http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php and see [`this answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/670012/) to check.

Comment: Above comment will solve the problem.If you are new to mysqli then i will suggest to learn pdo which is safe to query the database.

Comment: Is your DB class namespaced? If so, you need `new \mysqli()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the error corrected by enabling/editing the following config in `php.ini`:

1st (uncomment and add config):

```
include_path = "C:\php\includes"
```

2nd (uncomment):

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

3rd (uncomment and edit config):

```
extension=D:/PHP/ext/php_mysql.dll
extension=D:/PHP/ext/php_mysqli.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure is enabled under php.ini just find php_mysqli.dll and remove semi-colon and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Christian Mark is right but I think it need:

4rd Copy php.ini to "C:\Windows". On my computer, need copy it to "C:\Windows", Because phpinfo() output "Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows" and "Loaded Configuration File: C:\Windows\php.ini"

5rd login out Computer and login in.

Then it work for me.

If I don't do 4,5rd, It's also don't  work for me, the phpinfo output include_path is not my configured. and extension_di also not. run the test also not work.

Comment: Instead of copying php.ini to C:\Windows, you can also just set the PHPRC environment variable to the path(s) of your php.ini ... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43531113/1593026 for more info