# Fatal error: Class ‘mysqli’ not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\query.php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I’m in the middle of E10-4 from 'Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript' by Robin Nixon.  I have enjoyed the book until two days ago when I got to exercise 10-4 where I was asked to run the following php program:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
  $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);

  $query  = "SELECT * FROM classics";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  if (!$result) die($conn->error);

  $rows = $result->num_rows;

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Author: '   . $result->fetch_assoc()['author']   . '<br>';
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Title: '    . $result->fetch_assoc()['title']    . '<br>';
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Category: ' . $result->fetch_assoc()['category'] . '<br>';
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'Year: '     . $result->fetch_assoc()['year']     . '<br>';
    $result->data_seek($j);
    echo 'ISBN: '     . $result->fetch_assoc()['isbn']     . '<br><br>';
  }

  $result->close();
  $conn->close();
?>
```

I get the two following error messages:

1. Fatal error: Class ‘mysqli’ not found in
   C:\xampp\htdocs\code\query.php
2. PHP Fatal error: Class ‘mysqli’ not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\code\query.php

I’m running the following systems:

- Windows 7 Home Premium
- PHP 5.6.8
- XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1
- Apache 2.4.12
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev -
- PHP extension: mysqli

I have searched stackoverflow and found a few posts about similar problems but could not pull any information out to solve the problem.  I’m new to programming but the responses where over my head.  I really have enjoyed this book but this Fatal error is keeping me from doing some great stuff with php and I'm not sure what I can do if I don't get past this issue.  I'm sure it is simple to fix.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666811/fatal-error-class-mysqli-not-found
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21864663/mysqli-not-found-error

Comment: Also, for your knowledge hunger I'd check out CodeAcademy. Also, try Ruby, it's much easier to use.